# Does each LNCS volume have a proof-reading chance for authors?

Tags: publications, conference, publishers

I have a conference paper that will be included in [LNCS](https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs). But recently, I found a few typos in the camera-ready version of the conference. I am wondering whether I will still receive a proof-reading notification from the publisher so that I can fix the typos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Springer LNCS the workflow is like this:

1. You submit the source code of your article to the publisher.
2. The publisher takes care of the final typesetting.
3. You will get the page proofs back from the publisher, with maybe two or three days time to respond to it.
4. The publisher will then do the final edits based on your response. You will not see what it looks like until it is published.

In step 3 you are expected to give feedback on the mistakes introduced by the publisher, not correct your own mistakes that were there already in the source material.

But with minor typos you can always try your luck and mention also those. Maybe the publisher is willing to fix also those.